# Command 'python' is available in '/usr/bin/python'

Tags: python, path

Whenever I try to use Python via the terminal, I get this message:

```
bash: export: `:/usr/bin': not a valid identifier
a:~$ python
Command 'python' is available in '/usr/bin/python'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
python: command not found
```

Then I use this command to add the path:

```
export PATH=$PATH=:/usr/bin
```

But whenever I run the terminal again I get the same error.

**UPDATE**
The problem was solved after following the instruction here: https://askubuntu.com/a/20955 & here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/786349/bash-export-not-a-valid-identifier.

Comment: I've already verified that it is not there. Then used the suggested command and still that did not work.

Comment: Start a new terminal (or log out / log in again) to clear the broken `PATH` from your experiment. Also, how did you "verify" that `/usr/bin` is not in your default `PATH`?

Comment: Can you run the `env | grep 'PATH'` command and verify it is correct in there? Also if you would like to persistently add `/usr/bin` to your path environmental variable you should add that line to your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`(unless you are on a mac).

Comment: can you print the content of your `PATH` variable with `echo $PATH` ?

Comment: How exactly do you invoke python? What does `type python` tell you?

Comment: @SatōKatsura I did that. again did not work.

Comment: @Jesse_b I did add it by hand but still the same problem. Also, it is corret

Comment: @user7631183, I'm not sure you are fully reading the comments in here.  Please provide an answer to the questions that have been asked.  You can update your question to include the output in codeblocks of commands that have been requested.

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin"
```

Comment: That did not work.

Comment: @user7631183 That's an opportunity for you to learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
export $PATH:/usr/bin
```

This would give rise to the error message

```
bash: export: `:/usr/bin': not a valid identifier
```

But only if `$PATH` was empty or misspelled.

Likewise,

```
export $PATH
```

would also give the same error message if `$PATH` was `:/usr/bin`.

But

```
export PATH=$PATH=:/usr/bin
```

is perfectly legal, but would distort the last path entry in the old `$PATH` value by adding a `=` to the end of it.

The correct line to have is

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin"
```

but it's unlikely that this is needed as `/usr/bin` is *very likely* already in the system default path that all users have. It is therefore more likely that you somehow unset or seriously mangle the value of `$PATH` somewhere in your shell startup files.

Review your `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` files and make sure that the syntax is correct whenever you modify your `PATH`. Then open a new terminal and test it.